# Is there a way to solve $x^2 = \cos(x)$ using algebraic manipulations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

A graphing calculator shows that the curves $ y = x^2$ and $y = \cos(x)$ have two intesects.

This is an intuitive argument to think that the solution set of  $x^2 = \cos(x)$ is not empty.

However, it seems more diffcult to find these solutions algebraically:

$x^2 = \cos (x) \iff \sqrt {x^2} = \sqrt {\cos(x)} \iff \lvert x \rvert = \sqrt{\cos(x)} \iff x= \sqrt{\cos(x)} \lor \lvert x \rvert = - \sqrt{\cos(x)}$

... which is not much better...

Symbolab , for example, gives no answer for this kind of problem.

In which direction should I look for in order to solve such an equation?

Comment: I don't think that the solution can be written as a closed formula using standard functions.

Comment: The only approach that I could conjure involves focusing on the [Taylor Series for the cosine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Trigonometric_functions).  However, I don't see any way of using that to solve your posted question.  Therefore, from my perspective, I see no improvement on the answer of Claude Leibovici.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equation being transcendental, you will need a numerical method. However, you can general decent *approximations* using series.

Starting with a simple one
$$x^2-\cos(x)=-1+\frac{3 x^2}{2}+O\left(x^4\right)$$
$$x_0=\sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}=0.816497$$ which is "close" to $\frac \pi 4$. Repeat
$$x^2-\cos(x)=\left(\frac{\pi ^2}{9}-\frac{1}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{2 \pi
   }{3}\right) \left(x-\frac{\pi }{3}\right)+\frac{5}{4} \left(x-\frac{\pi
   }{3}\right)^2+O\left(\left(x-\frac{\pi }{3}\right)^3\right)$$ Solve the quadratic equation to get
$$x_1=\frac{1}{15} \left(-3 \sqrt{3}+\pi +\sqrt{27+24 \sqrt{3} \pi +\frac{1}{36}
   \left(3240-144 \pi ^2\right)}\right)=0.824776$$ while the solution given by Newton method is $x=0.824132$.

Now, if you want to polish the root, use Newton method which will converge very fast. With a ridiculous number of figures
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 0.82477576164207041812 \\
 1 & 0.82413254492690137373 \\
 2 & 0.82413231230255285297 \\
 3 & 0.82413231230252242296
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

After @user2661923's comment, let me use the Taylor series built around $x=0$  of
$$f(x)=x^2-\cos(x)$$
and then series reversion to get
$$x=t\Bigg[1+\frac{t^2}{72}+\frac{11 t^4}{51840}-\frac{47 t^6}{8709120}-\frac{26699
   t^8}{37623398400}-\frac{1011581 t^{10}}{29797731532800}+O\left(t^{12}\right)  \Bigg]$$ where $t=\sqrt{\frac{2 }{3}(f(x)+1)}$. SInce we want $f(x)=0$, this quite limited series gives,as approximation,
$$x=\frac{228392621799607}{113138261913600 \sqrt{6}}=0.824132$$

Comment: +1 to your answer.  See also the comment that I posted, following the original question.